# how to cd to directory OR directory file is in?

Tags: shell-script, cd-command

If I do `cd "user/Dropbox/foo.txt"`, I get `-bash: cd: user/Dropbox/foo.txt: Not a directory`. But my intention in this case is always the same: I want to `cd` to the directory the file is in.

I tried this:

```
function smartcd
{
    dirname=$(dirname "$1");
    cd $dirname;
}
```

But it doesn't work because when $1 is a directory, `dirname "$1"` returns the parent directory, not the directory itself.

How can I create a command that will cd to the directory itself if `$1` is a directory, or to the directory the file is in if `$1` is a file?

Comment: Doesn't zsh do this already? If not, maybe it should...?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to test $1 for a file first:

if test -f "$1"; then
  cd `dirname ...`
else
  cd "$1"
fi